# PHP: pushing array into array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, array-push

I have googled and used various approaches from this site, but somehow my problem isn't getting resolved.

Here is my problem: I have an array named `$color` and I want to add arrays into this (multidimensional) array, from within a function.

```
$color = array();

function hex2RGB($hex){
    $hex = ltrim($hex,'#');
    $a = hexdec(substr($hex,0,2));
    $b = hexdec(substr($hex,2,2));
    $c = hexdec(substr($hex,4,2));
    $rgb = array($a, $b, $c);
    array_push($color,$rgb);
}

hex2RGB("#97B92B");
hex2RGB("#D1422C");
hex2RGB("#66CAEA");
```

I know the function creates a good "rgb"-array with 3 values, I tested with screen output. But using `array_push` or `$color[] = $rgb;` doesn't add that array to the `$color` array. No error is shown, the "color"-array just stays empty.

Comment: can't you just have a simple array `return` on the end and assign it

Comment: [Variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: Sidenote: this user [contribution note](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php#25190) shows a nice way to convert...

Comment: Thanks, FirstOne. sscanf seems like a handy function, didn't know of its existence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to globalise your $color array to use it inside functions.

```
<?php
$color = array();

function hex2RGB($hex){
global $color; // magic happens here

$hex = ltrim($hex,'#');
$a = hexdec(substr($hex,0,2));
$b = hexdec(substr($hex,2,2));
$c = hexdec(substr($hex,4,2));
$rgb = array($a, $b, $c);
array_push($color,$rgb);
}
```

fixes your problem.

For more information read the [Scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) section of the php tutorial

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the `$color` array to the function by reference

```
function hex2RGB($hex, &$color){ // '&' means changes to $color will persist
   ...
}
$color = [];
hex2RGB('#...',$color);//after this line, $color will contain the data you want
```

I would favor this over using `global` within a function because with this approach, you control exactly which array gets modified (you pass it when calling the function).  Using `global` can lead to unintended consequences if you forget when calling a function that it will change other variables in your scope.  The better design is to keep your code modularized (just search for recommendations on the use of `global` vars to see for yourself).

Comment: I was looking for this (an option _without_ global) +1

Answer (score 0):

See below. You need to allow the global variable $color to be used in the function by using the "global" keyword:

```
$color = array();

function hex2RGB($hex){
global $color; //<----------------this line here is needed to use $color
$hex = ltrim($hex,'#');
$a = hexdec(substr($hex,0,2));
$b = hexdec(substr($hex,2,2));
$c = hexdec(substr($hex,4,2));
$rgb = array($a, $b, $c);
array_push($color,$rgb);
}

hex2RGB("#97B92B");
hex2RGB("#D1422C");
hex2RGB("#66CAEA");
```